# WordPress Plugin Question

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

Is it possible to use plugins on my blog for WordPress.com? There are some very nice tutorials on how to do this if I have WordPress installed on my own server, but I am using wordpress.com.
Does anyone know if they allow this? It seems like the expected "Plugin" category on my dashboard is missing.

Many thanks,
brett

Comment: Title should be revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already has some plugins built in such as [Akismet](http://akismet.com/), but you can not add your own on Wordpress.com (you can't even add other themes and can only use the ones they provide).

Here is a list of the [free features](http://en.wordpress.com/features/).  With [premium paid for features](http://en.wordpress.com/products/), you also have the ability to use your own domain name and can customize your CSS (as well as some other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress.com doesn't let you install your own plugins.